# How to get cell index from uiview in uitableviewcell (swift/xcode)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

I have two `UIViewControllers` called upVote and downVote in `MyTableViewCell` class.  I have added the gesture recognizers for tapping these views programmatically but am not sure how to get the parent cell or index of the cell so I know which cell the `UIView` that was tapped is in.  How do I get the cell or index of the tapped cell in the functions handleTapUp and handleTapDown?

Here is my class

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var upVote: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var downVote: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        let tapUp = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapUp:")
        tapUp.delegate = self
        upVote.addGestureRecognizer(tapUp)

        let tapDown = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapDown:")
        tapDown.delegate = self
        downVote.addGestureRecognizer(tapDown)

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state

    }

    func handleTapUp(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        // handling code
        // get cell(index)
    }

    func handleTapDown(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        // handling code
        // get cell()
    }

}
```

I have tried self.superclass to get the uitableviewcell, and when i print the debug description it say uitableviewcell, but whenever I try to do anything else with the object I get an error that self.superclass is type AnyObject.  I have tried declaring/casting self.superclass in many different ways and none have worked.  This seems like it should be simple so hopefully I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Declare a variable in your customCellClass:-
       var indexForCell : NSIndexPath!
- In your ViewControllers where you are `deque`ing the cells in the function `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` add this :-

  ```
   cell.indexForCell = indexPath
  ```
- Now access the `indexForCell` in your functions in your class:-

  ```
  func handleTapUp(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {

  let rowValue = indexForCell.row

  }

  func handleTapDown(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
  // handling code
  // get cell()
   }
  ```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you.  I was going about it all wrong.